Image denoising of a grey background with black spots
How can I highlight the black spots in the image below for detection?

I've tried a lot of things, gaussian filter, change of contrast, contour filters... but nothing really worked. Currently, I'm trying to find a solution using python libraries, cv2, PIL, scikit-image,etc.
My goal is to identify each black spot.

Try a median blur about the size of the spots followed by adaptive thresholding.

An attempt at fleshing out Fred's advice (@fmw42):
magick spots.png -colorspace gray -statistic median 19x19 -lat 49x49-1% result.jpg


Maybe work on the parameters a little to tune it.

Slightly different approach:
magick spots.png -colorspace gray -median 15x15 -normalize -threshold 15% result.jpg



Another slightly different approach:
magick spots.png -colorspace gray -median 15x15 -median 7x7 -normalize -threshold 25% result.jpg


With OpenCV, that will look something like this:
import cv2 as cv

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('spots.png',cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Median blur 15 and save debug
filtered = cv.medianBlur(im,15)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-median15.png', filtered)

# Median blur 7 and save debug
filtered = cv.medianBlur(filtered,7)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-median7.png', filtered)

# Normalize to full range
norm = cv2.normalize(filtered, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-norm.png', norm)

# Threshold
res = norm > 127
cv.imwrite('result.png', (res * 255).astype(np.uint8))


Note:
There is a Python C-types binding of ImageMagick called wand so you can port my answer across to Python. Here is an example.

Mark, you might point out that your solution is Imagemagick not Python as mentioned by the OP.

Mark, you might clean up your result by some morphology to remove the smaller spots. Or use connected components to filter by area.
